# How does Terraform (v0.13) fetch the newest version of a (third-party) provider binary?

Tags: terraform

With the newest Terraform version v0.13, I'm trying to get my head around how to set up a provider registry for third-party Terraform providers.

Take the following `terraform` configuration block:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    happy_cloud = {
      source = "registry.example.com/acme/happy_cloud"
    }
  }
}
```

Fetching from `registry.example.com`, how would Terraform know what the newest available version of the `acme/happy_cloud` provider binary is? (e.g. v1.2.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terraform finds the specified providers by playing the client role of [the provider registry protocol](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/provider-registry-protocol.html).

Given the source address `registry.example.com/acme/happy_cloud`, Terraform will:

- Perform [service discovery](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/provider-registry-protocol.html#service-discovery) on the hostname `registry.example.com` to find its provider registry base URL, if it has one.
- Call the [List Available Versions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/provider-registry-protocol.html#list-available-versions) operation as `acme/happy_cloud/versions` to learn which versions are available for that provider.
- Select the newest version matching the given version constraint (which in your case is empty, so unconstrained) using [the Semantic Versioning precedence rules](https://semver.org/). Let's assume for this example that v1.2.3 is the newest version.
- Call the [Find a Provider package](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/provider-registry-protocol.html#find-a-provider-package) operation as `acme/happy_cloud/1.2.3/download/linux/amd64` (or a different OS/arch depending on your current platform) to get the package locations and signing keys for that version built for that target platform.
- Finally, download and verify the indicated package file.